# Imap analysing with wireshark

Tags: imap

I have this code (its a exercise example, so its nothing illegal =) ) viewed in Wireshark

> a0001 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN Y2VvAGNlbwBsMldCTlJpcw==\r\n

its an IMAP protocol and obviously using the PLAIN auth method.

so the username and password shall be included in that section "Y2VvAGNlbwBsMldCTlJpcw=="

Can anyone explain to me what `\r` and `\n` mean?
- and what does `==` stands for at the end of the string?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is explained in the [AUTHENTICATE Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.2.2) section of RFC3501 (the IMAP protocol). `AUTHENTICATE PLAIN` is one of many possible authentication mechanisms, and it is described in [RFC4616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4616.txt). The example in Section 5 of RFC4616 is quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

The `\r` and `\n` are a way of displaying the ASCII newline and carriage return characters.  They together just mean end of line.

The `Y2VvAGNlbwBsMldCTlJpcw==` part is in what is called BASE64 encoding.  It represents binary data in printable characters by reencoding it as 6-bit characters (instead of 8-byte bits).  The == are part of that encoding specification.